# Using resource in controller before its loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on an angular application i'll post some sample code here.

In My Service i have a method that access a rest api via $resource:

```
function getData() {
    resource.get({}, function success(data) {
        return data;
    }, function error() {
        console.log('error')
    })
}
```

Now over in a controller that has been injected with the service i attempt to use the data with some conditions from the previous page that are passed through as a routeParameter as follows:

```
$scope.data = MyResource.getData()
$scope.editingObject = angular.copy($scope.data[$routeParams.objIndex])
```

On my view i would like to bind to `$scope.editingObject` but since that code executes immediately and the data may not have arrived back from the server i receive the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Now i understand that i cannot access the array before the data has arrived back from the server but my question is more about how do i construct this service in such a way that i can access that data?

To resolve this issue i have attempted to place a watch on `$scope.data` and monitor for the data to arrive but it never fires when the data does arrive. i have confirmed this using console.log in a set timeout to check after a few seconds if the data has arrived at which point it has... and the object is updated to reflect this.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction regarding services, resources and accessing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to see the `$watch()` code because it should fire when data is received. But anyways, you should use the promise returned from service:

```
MyResource.getData().then(function(data) {
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.editingObject = angular.copy($scope.data[$routeParams.objIndex])
});
```

Comment: Hi package, i've just tried this out but i'm receiving TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I've attached the sample of the code im using to test your example.
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TNxwhxVL)

Comment: You do not return anything from `OkrsServices.test()`, therefore `.then()` is invoked on `undefined`. Add a `return` statement before `okrsmodel.get`

Comment: Thanks for your help. i figured out the issue was both what you mentioned above... and in my version of angular i have to put $promise.then() otherwise it would not recognize it.

Your help was most appreciated i've been stuck on this for two days.